# legend command in zoo

Tags: r, plot, time-series, zoo

I am trying to plot multiple time series on the same graph.

Following is a snippet of the file:

```
Date        FP1M      FP3M    FP6M
2001-12-01  6.44      6.34    6.36
2002-01-01  5.70      6.00    5.99
```

When I use plot() in conjunction with lines(), I get the graph but not the x(i.e., time) axis.

Following is the code:

```
z <- read.table("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\IRPfinal.txt",header=TRUE,sep="")
d <- as.Date((z$Date),format="%m/%d/%Y")
a <- z[,"FP1M"]
b <- z[,"FP3M"]
c <- z[,"FP6M"]
plot(d,a,xaxt="n",type="l",xlab="Timeline",lwd=5,ylab="Percent",xaxt="n",
     main="Forward Premia on the US Dollar")
lines(d,b,type="l",col="red",lwd=5)
lines(d,c,type="l",col="blue",lwd=5)
legend(0,col=c("black","red","blue"),lwd=5,legend=c("FP1M","FP3M","FP6M"))
axis(1, d ,format(d, "%b  %y"), cex.axis = .4)
```

Following error shows up:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Why is the date axis not showing up properly?

I tried zoo package which solves the above problem but now I am not able to add a legend to the graph.Is the legend command not supported by zoo?

Comment: <blinking>`Please insert reproducible code.`</blinking>

Comment: The format used does not correspond to the file contents shown.  Also, its probably easier to just use lattice graphics as in Oscar's answer but if you want to use classic graphics create a panel function which displays the legend in panel 1.  See the examples in `?plot.zoo` .

Answer (score 1):

With `zoo` and `lattice`:

```
dat <- "Date        FP1M      FP3M    FP6M
2001-12-01  6.44      6.34    6.36
2002-01-01  5.70      6.00    5.99"

z <- read.zoo(textConnection(dat), header=TRUE)
xyplot(z, superpose=TRUE, xlab="Timeline", ylab="Percent",
       main="Forward Premia on the US Dollar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your help.Am trying your suggestions out. Meanwhile, I was able to add the legend while using the zoo package using the **locator(1)** argument so the issue was apparantly that I was giving improper coordinates for the legend box origin.

Further,some help from the webpage (link below) enabled me to do even without zoo. First one has to use **as.Date(as.character())** on the first column to read that column's entries as dates.Then the entire data-set has to be indexed by the first column using the **order()** command.The axis then starts appearing as time.

Sorry if all this appears elementary.I am a novice without any prior programming experience.

Here's the link that helped :

http://blog.earlh.com/index.php/2009/07/plotting-multiple-series-in-r-part-4-in-a-series/